# Convert Json to Dictionary C#

Tags: c#, json, dictionary

I want transform this json in Dictionary for make one loop

Look my code:

```
string json = @"{""name"":""Joe"",""note"":{""a1"":10,""a2"":9,""a3"":5}}";

Dictionary<string, object> dictionaryLevelOne = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, object>>(json);   
Dictionary<string, object> dictionaryLevelTwo = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, object>>(dictionaryLevelOne ["note"]);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to pass `dictionaryLevelOne["note"]` as a string.

```
string json = @"{""name"":""Joe"",""note"":{""a1"":10,""a2"":9,""a3"":5}}";

Dictionary<string, object> dictionaryLevelOne = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, object>>(json);
Dictionary<string, object> dictionaryLevelTwo = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, object>>(dictionaryLevelOne["note"].ToString());
```